# why was http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167520/ rejected as a migration out?

Tags: discussion

Why was https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167520/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-hc-06-bluetooth-module-communication-with-android-dev rejected as a migration out? I saw it hit the android stack but now it is back there and closed.

This question is purely about Android usage and development and emulation, and only tangently about electronics.

Comment: Android.SE people have been pinged.  The O.P. wishes to emulate his future Bluetooth device with an Android device (in lieu of the future Bluetooth device). That's an Android development question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their site scope, dev questions are off topic. Dumb. Apparently those questions belong on Stack Overflow.